# How to get the window viewport from a jquery selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have a web page with several iframes. From the context of one of the parent iframe I can generate a selector to any of the children iframes:

```
$sel = $("#iframe-"+id).contents().find("#"+key);
```

My problem is to make the reverse process. I want to get the *window* viewport of a given $sel that I have obtained this way. I have tried this without success:

```
$(window, $sel)
```

Note that the variable $sel may be used in any context, the parent or any of the children.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? And is this all from the same domain and protocol?

Comment: I think you can't get the viewport of a given `$sel`. But you certainly can deal with the `parent` property when your code is executed in `iframe` (like `parent.$("#my-selector")`).

Comment: All same domain and protocol. I need to access from the one of the iframes to another to read a global variable (CKEDITOR) in order to get the content of a rich textarea.

Comment: Not using JQuery, you can communicate from IFrame to parent using messaging. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.postMessage

Comment: Still having the same problem @MikeCheel : I don't know which "window" I have to send the message. Is that window what I need to get.

Comment: Perhaps your iframes can message the parent (using the messaging) and you can include the iframe info you need in the message (which is just a plain javascript object of your devising).